# Different floating point precision in Matrix multiplication in Python and C++

Tags: python, c++, precision, floating-accuracy

I am trying to do a very simple thing

1. take a square shape 2d array
2. take its transpose
3. multiply the array with its transpose

I am trying to perform the above steps in C++ and Python as shown in the programs below:

**C++ Program:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>  // For setw

int main() {
    float R[16] = {
        0.5, 0.63245553, -0.5, 0.31622777,
        0.5, 0.31622777, 0.5, -0.63245553,
        0.5, -0.31622777, 0.5, 0.63245553,
        0.5, -0.63245553, -0.5, -0.31622777
    };

    const int nRows = 4;
    const int nCols = 4;
    float result[nRows][nRows] = { 0 };

    // Perform matrix multiplication
    for (int i = 0; i < nRows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < nRows; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < nCols; k++) {
                result[i][j] += R[i * nCols + k] * R[j * nCols + k];
            }
        }
    }

    // Print the result with left-aligned columns and a padding of 15 characters
    for (int i = 0; i < nRows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < nRows; j++) {
            std::cout << std::left << std::setw(15) << result[i][j] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Python Program:**

```
import numpy as np


R = np.array([
    0.5, 0.63245553, -0.5, 0.31622777,
    0.5, 0.31622777, 0.5, -0.63245553,
    0.5, -0.31622777, 0.5, 0.63245553,
    0.5, -0.63245553, -0.5, -0.31622777
]).reshape(4, 4)

result = np.dot(R, R.T)

# Print the result
print(result)
```

**Problem:** As can be seen in the above programs, I am using exactly the same input array/matrix. But the precision of results of the multiplicaiton is quite different.

Except for the diagonal, most of the values are quite different with huge differences in precision. How can I get the same precision in both languages? **Why are even the signs flipped for some elements?**

> **C++ Results:**

```
1               -1.49012e-08    0               -7.45058e-09
-1.49012e-08    1               0               0
0               0               1               -1.49012e-08
-7.45058e-09    0               -1.49012e-08    1
```

> **Python Results:**

```
[[1.00000000e+00 2.77555756e-17 0.00000000e+00 5.32461714e-11]
 [2.77555756e-17 1.00000000e+00 5.32461852e-11 0.00000000e+00]
 [0.00000000e+00 5.32461852e-11 1.00000000e+00 2.77555756e-17]
 [5.32461714e-11 0.00000000e+00 2.77555756e-17 1.00000000e+00]]
```

Comment: use `double` rather than `float` when aiming for max precision.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai: with `double`, it works but why would the signs be different if I am using float?

Comment: because floating point math is not exact. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken. With `float`s the value `-1.49012e-08` is as close to `0` as you can expect it to get in the presence of rounding errors

Comment: I dont think this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken is the right duplicate, but it is closely related and the top answer refers to https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html which should cover what you are looking for

Comment: On most platforms, Python uses a 64-bit floating point representation.  And on most platforms C uses 64-bit floating point for `double`, and 32-bit floating point for `float`.  People almost always use `double` in C, rather than `float`.  Using `float` in C is asking for trouble, unless you *really* don't want 64-bit floating point.

Comment: You should have both programs display maximum precision with least amount of rounding. For example, C++ prints `1` whereas Python prints `1.00000000e+00`, which is `1`. Don't print in Scientific Format, print out a lot of decimals.

Comment: As an aside, almost certainly what `np.dot` will end up actually doing is *not* the naive algorithm you have implemented, it will use one of various BLAS/LAPACK backends which are heavily optimized

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: I am facing some problem even within python and getting different values. Just now asked a different question about it (maybe that's the reason): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77239589/python-generating-different-results-for-matrix-multiplicaiton

Comment: If I may paraphrase: _Why are computational results with type `float` so bad?_ Answer: Round-off errors accumulate rapidly when you use type `float`. It is good for only 6 or 7 decimal digits of precision, and you can easily lose 2 or 3 of those in a chain of calculations.